# Is it possible to change the navigationBarStyle on runtime in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to change the background color of the navigation bar while opening the the scene.

I tried to achieve it by this but it doesn't work.

```
Actions.scene({navigationBarStyle:{backgroundColor:'red'}});
```

And this gives syntax error

```
Actions.scene({navigationBarStyle:{{backgroundColor:'red'}}});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the prop `navigationBarStyle` to `headerStyle`.

```
Actions.scene({headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#FF0000'}});
```